# PHP: Converting blob content to image

Tags: php, image, oracle, blob

Although there are couple of similar threats, my question is not answered.

I have extracted blob content from an oracle database that looks like this:

bab216da9a85b9df1b6f4fdd84629838e71919a00645e2a966bb6851ac6dd804da27988672ca0f0

How can I convert it to a jpeg? What decoding function do I need?

Comment: A BLOB is a binary data structure.  What you posted does not appear to be binary.  My guess is that you either did some sort of encoding of the data when you extracted it or that the process that inserted the image encoded it before inserting it in the database.  You'd need to find out where and, more importantly, how the JPEG binary data was encoded in order to decode it.  Hopefully, it's something relatively simple like Base64 encoding or Base16 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like hexadecimal, but the oci_ functions should just use binary strings for blobs, so either you are doing an extra step of converting that to a hexadecimal string, or you accidentally inserted hexadecimal strings into your DB earlier. In any case, try hex2bin, i.e.:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo hex2bin($data);
```

If that doesn't work, please show your code.